# devise: instance the current_user using single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, single-table-inheritance

I am using rails 3.0.9 and devise for authentication. Now I'm trying to use single table inheritance because I need to use polymorphism, so I have two classes:  UserType1 and UserType2, which inherit from User class. I need that Devise instance correctly the current_user depending the type of user.

For example,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 #devise and other user logic 
end

class UserType1 < User
  def get_some_attribute
     return "Hello, my type is UserType1"
  end
end

class UserType2 < User
  def get_some_attribute
   return "Hello, my type is UserType2"
  end
end

In controller 

class MyController < ApplicationController
  def action
    @message = current_user.get_some_attribute #depending the type using polymorphism
    render :my_view
  end
end
```

Comment: I also has got the same problem

Comment: Have you added the 'type' column in users table? This is what makes Rails STI work.

Comment: Forget my bounty, `current_user` is well-instantiated.

Answer (score 5):

it's exactly what you need : http://blog.jeffsaracco.com/ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-user-model-with-devise-authentication

you need to override the sign in path method in your application controller, hope it help.

Comment: Sorry, as I said in comments + answer, forget my bounty, `current_user` is in fact well instantiated by STI mechanism. I put the bounty too fast without testing so far ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `get_some_attribute` method inside `User` model

```
Module User < ActiveRecord::Base

   #devise and other user logic 

   def get_some_attribute
      #You can put shared logic between the two users type here
   end

end
```

then, to override it in the user sub types, like this:

```
Module UserType1 < User

   def get_some_attribute
      super
      return "Hello, my type is UserType1"
   end

end

Module UserType2 < User

   def get_some_attribute
      super
      return "Hello, my type is UserType2"
   end

end
```

Then, `current_user.get_some_attribute` will work as you expecting, if you like to read more about overriding methods in Ruby, you can read about it [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_overriding_methods.html)

I added `super` as I assumed that you have some shared logic in `get_some_attribute`, as it will call `get_some_attribute` in User model, you can remove it if you don't need it.

Good luck!

Comment: I advise you to use only one user type and depend on roles to determine what to do..